# how to make edit and update multi select form in laravel

Tags: laravel, one-to-many, multi-select

i have a hostel with many facilities the store method is working but how to make edit and update the every hostel facilities 
this is the hostel facilities select input

```
   <select class="form-control m-select2" id="m_select2_2_3" name="facility_name[]"
                        multiple="multiple">

                    <optgroup label="select the hostel facility">

                        <option value="facility id">facility name</option>
                        <option value="facility id">facility name</option>
                        <option value="facility id">facility name</option>
                        <option value="facility id">facility name</option>
                        <option value="facility id">facility name</option>

                    </optgroup>
                </select>
```

the create method

```
   public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $hostel = new Hostel();
        $hostel->name = $request->name;
        $hostel->owner_id = 1; //Aut::user()->id;
        $hostel->type = $request->type;
        $hostel->phone = $request->phone;
        $hostel->email = $request->email;
        $hostel->description = $request->description;
        $hostel->save();
        $address = new Address();
        $address->hostel_id = $hostel->id;
        $address->province = $request->province;
        $address->state = $request->state;
        $address->rood = $request->rood;
        $address->alley = $request->alley;
        $address->station = $request->station;
        $address->home_number = $request->home_number;
        $address->save();
       );

       foreach ($request->facility_name as  $name) {

              $facility = new Facility;
              $facility->hostel_id = $hostel->id;
              $facility->facility_name = $name;
              $facility->save();
            }
      foreach ($request->file('file') as $file)
      {
         $isUploaded = uploadAttachments($hostel->id,0,0,$file,'attachments');
         if(!$isUploaded)

           Session()->flash('att_failed','File is note uploaded try again');
         }
        return redirect()->route('hostels_list');
    }
```

so how to make **edit the form with old input value and update**

Answer (score 0):

In Your Controller :

```
Facility::where(['hostel_id' => $hostel->hostel_id])->delete();

if($request->facility_name as $facility){
       $facility = new Facility;
       $facility->hostel_id = $hostel->id;
       $facility->facility_name = $name;
       $facility->save();
}
```